# Behaviour of $L^2$ functions at infinity

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Is it possible to prove that if $f\in L^2(\mathbb {R}) $ then $\exists\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\lvert f\rvert^2$ and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\lvert f\rvert^2=0$? If not, is it easy to find a counterexample?

Comment: Let $f(x)=n$ on $[n,n+{1\over n^4}]$, $n$ a positive integer, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: If we add the hypothesis  $f\in\mathcal{C}^0$ is it still so easy? I was thinking to something like a wavefunction in QM for example. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of steps over $[n,n+1/n^4]$, take "spikes". (You can smooth things out as nicely as you wish.)

Comment: A standard condition to have a zero limit is $f \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. $f \in L^2$ and $f' \in L^2$.

Comment: The shortest answer to the title: may be nasty.

Comment: If you assume $f$ to be uniformly continuous, your claims holds. Also, one can show that $f(x+n)\to0$ for almost all $x$ (for arbitrary $f\in L^p$, $p<\infty$).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrable function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ does not imply that limit $f(x)$ is zero](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85975/integrable-function-f-on-mathbb-r-does-not-imply-that-limit-fx-is-zero).  See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543866/finding-examples-for-a-non-negative-and-continuous-function-for-which-the-infini and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/92105/.