# Help with a proof that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to + \infty } f\left( x \right) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

The question is

> Let f be a continuous Lebesgue integrable function on $[0,+∞)$, show $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } f\left( x \right) = 0$.

**My attempt**:

Suppose $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } f\left( x \right) \neq 0$, then $\exists \epsilon>0 \forall x_0\in[1,+\infty)\exists x>x_0$ st. $|f(x)|>\epsilon$. Thus we can construct a sequence $x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < ...$ st. $f(x_k)>\epsilon$ for all $k=1,2,3...$.

Also by continuity, $\exists \delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3,...$ st. that $|f(x)|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for each $(x_k-\delta_k,x_k+\delta_k)$.

Thus $\int_1^{ + \infty } f  > \sum\limits_k {\varepsilon {\delta _k}}  = \varepsilon \sum\limits_k {{\delta _k}} $. However, it is possible for $\sum\limits_k {{\delta _k}} $ to converge, so **I am not able to conclude** $\int_1^{ + \infty } f  =  + \infty $.

Thank you!

Comment: There are continuous positive integrable functions such that $\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) = +\infty$. You need further assumptions to deduce $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Do you mean that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable?  (Not Lebesgue measurable)

Comment: Yes. I am sorry. That's my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Something like uniformly continuous or bounded variation would be helpful in this problem, otherwise, you can use your construction to create a counterexample.

Comment: [Being integrable does not help much](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543866/finding-examples-for-a-non-negative-and-continuous-function-for-which-the-infini)

Comment: I strongly suspect that there was an "almost everywhere" condition on this problem that got dropped.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't really help in the understanding but I love finding explicit examples. The function

$$f(x) = x(\cos^2 x)^{x^5}$$

is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$ and $f(2n\pi) =2n\pi, n = 1,2,\dots $

Comment: Spikes of given bases and heights are just as explicit, if you ask me...

Comment: By "explicit" I meant "easy to write down as a formula in terms of elementary functions".