# Fresnel integrals are not Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

How does one prove that the Fresnel integrals
$$
S(x) = \int_0^x \! \sin(t^2) \, \mathrm{d}t, \qquad C(x) = \int_0^x \! \cos(t^2) \, \mathrm{d}t
$$
do not belong to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Do you mean to show that $$\int^\infty_0\lvert \sin(t^2) \rvert dt \,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\, \int^\infty_0 \lvert \cos(t^2) \rvert dt$$ diverge or that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert S(x) \rvert dx \,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\,\, \int^\infty_{-\infty} \lvert C(x) \rvert dx$$ diverge?

Comment: The latter. I would like to show that $S, C \not\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\lim_{\lvert x \rvert \to \infty} \lvert S(x) \rvert = \sqrt{\pi/8}$, we can find $M \in \mathbb R$ such that for $\lvert x \rvert > M$, we have $$\lvert S(x) \rvert \ge \sqrt{\pi/16}.$$ But then $$\int^\infty_{-\infty} \lvert S(x) \rvert dx \ge \int^M_{-M} \lvert S(x) \rvert dx + \int^\infty_M \sqrt{\pi/16} \,\,dx + \int^{-M}_{-\infty} \sqrt{\pi/16}\,\, dx = \infty$$ and similarly for $C(x)$.